# Cannot select the tag name- JS

Tags: namespaces, tags

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h1").innerHTML="changed";

<h1> Yet to change</h1>
```

Might be a stupid question but can someone please tell me why's this not working?

Comment: Actually seems to be working on jsfiddle but not on my pc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` will return all `h1` elements in an array.  You'll need to be more selective in some way; for example, this would choose the first `h1` and set its `innerHTML` to "changed":

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "changed"
```

Comment: Hey, got it! Dunno if I can rep tho

Comment: You can vote up once you get to 15 rep, but you can [**accept an answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) now (and receive +2 toward getting your rep up to where you can vote up).

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a Collection or a NodeList which you need to use an index to address.

Try

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML="changed";
```